# How to disable the WiFi using network-manager permanently?

Tags: wireless, boot, network-manager, settings

How to disable the wifi on boot? I'm using network-manager to manage the wifi connection and when I disable this, setting is temporary to the current session. 
Exists therefore a method to make persistent settings for network-manager? thanks

Comment: Duplicate?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24171/how-can-i-keep-a-wireless-cards-radio-powered-off-by-default

Comment: @Mussnoon My question is specific to network-manager, who in an older version of ubuntu kept the settings at boot, not now. And because it's a widespread problem in other forums, wondering if anyone knows why ...

Comment: You can also edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and remove the `wlan0, wlan1 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to right click on the network manager applet and select `disable wireless`, if this isn't being saved over your session then please report it as a bug:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

If on the other hand you want to prevent your computer from automatically joining networks, then you must go into the network editing and either remove and uncheck the use automatically option for each network.

If you want to save power, then please use the advice in the guide mentioned by Mussnoon above, shutting off with rfkill will be most effective:

[How can I keep a wireless card's radio powered off by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24171/how-can-i-keep-a-wireless-cards-radio-powered-off-by-default)

By running `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` add this:

```
rfkill block wifi
```

before the line `exit 0`

Comment: Then I will report the bug...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 the on-off-state survives a reboot just fine

Comment: It seems like the rfkill in rc.local only works if you add a sleep before: `/bin/sleep 10 && rfkill block wifi` (see [Turn off the Wireless card on each boot](http://askubuntu.com/a/490490) )