# Airplane mode not persistent after boot

Tags: networking, airplane-mode

When I enable airplane mode on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS through the network settings (dash->network) it will be disabled after a reboot and the networking capabilities back to normal.

When traveling for many hours with multiple flights I would like this setting to persist across reboots. How can I achieve this? And why is this not the case by default?

Comment: See the radio silence part of: [How can I keep a wireless card's radio powered off by default?](https://askubuntu.com/a/534752/767056) which came from [Turn off the Wireless card on each boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490429/turn-off-the-wireless-card-on-each-boot)