# Is there a terminal command to verify if Wifi is enabled?

Tags: wireless, command-line

Since my laptop doesnt have a Wireless Network LED indicator, I want to know if there is a command to verify if it is on or off (I'm installing the wireless drivers, so I can't tell if it is set on or off by seeing the list of wireless conections next to the clock)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Edit:

`nmcli` changed a lot (I am using 16.04) from its previous version. See the original answer below.

**To see the connectivity status**

```
$ nmcli general status
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

**To see only wifi status**

```
$ nmcli radio  wifi 
enabled
```

**To see the active connection**

```
$ nmcli connection show --active
NAME         UUID                                  TYPE        DEVICE 
VolCSe  5u6h4521-7k1p-20r3-3g4x-fg19his0j3s8  802-11-wireless  wlp2s0
```

There are some nice addlitions like, **to get the available wifi network informations**,

```
$ nmcli device wifi 
*  SSID                        MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*  VolCSe                      Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  73      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
   Sach                        Infra  4     54 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
   iKCP                        Infra  5     54 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA2      
   TP-LINK_POCKET_3            Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  12      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
```

<sup>**Note**: *I have used fictitious ssid and uuid info above.*</sup>

---

#### Old answer:

You can use `nmcli` for this purpose. Open a terminal type in terminal,

```
nmcli nm
```

You will have output like,

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       disabled        disabled   enabled         disabled
```

See the third and fourth column which contains information of your interest.

If you want to be more specific only to wifi, then try in terminal,

```
nmcli nm wifi
```

it will show the wifi status only,

```
WIFI      
disabled
```

Comment: For me, it is showing enabled no matter if I press the keys to activate the wifi. Maybe the keys aren't working, is there a command to enable/disable like it was the key?

Comment: try `nmcli nm wifi on` to enable and `nmcli nm wifi off` to disable

Comment: yes, this is telling the right result after the installation of the driver. So, the answer is "nmcli nm wifi". Thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me. It just says `WIFI unknown`. I could use `sudo rfkill block wifi` and `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` instead, as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26199/how-to-switch-off-wifi-on-startup-or-from-the-console). Note that my computer is quite old, so it might be that the `network-manager` did not recognize my hardware. Also, the OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

```
rfkill list
```

This wil show devices that are either software or hardware blocked. In my case it's not blocked and wifi is on:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

When the driver is up and running, the wireless interface should show up in the list when using the following command:

```
ifconfig
```

Comment: For me, it shows `Soft blocked: no` even if my WiFi is turned off (although hardware is enabled).

Answer (score 3):

As of 15.04 (and later, including 16.04 LTS), the [nmcli](http://manpg.es/nmcli) command has changed.  There, you'll use:

```
⟫ nmcli radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

or just

```
⟫ nmcli radio wifi
enabled
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i used below commands and the output was 1 if the wifi was enabled else 0. You can try and good luck.

```
nmcli r wifi | grep enabled | grep -v not | wc -l
```

Comment: this still works in 2024 (tested on Debian 12), but what does `r` mean? I scrolled through all of the `man nmcli` and I don't see such a command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WICD. if it not installed, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

Once installed, run it to see connectivity, Access point connected to, properties, IP settings, and much more.

[image]

Comment: it only shows the eth0 since the wlan0 isn't 'installed' yet

Comment: If wireless not enabled or installed, it won't show that.

Comment: `nm-tool` doesn't exist anymore.  Just an FYI.

Comment: The question asks how to check connectivity from terminal. Your answer involves using a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

**iwlist scanning** should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `ip address` or `ip addr` command instead of slightly old `ifconfig`. If you know the name of your interface device, you can use `ip addr show <device name>`. Here's an example ( notice `state UP` part, which for disabled interface shows up as `DOWN`):

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:53:49:3d:53:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan7
       valid_lft 86183sec preferred_lft 86183sec
    inet6 fe80::439:869d:d6ed:c983/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the cli commands listed here there is a cli utility called: nmtui (more info here: https://www.unixarena.com/2015/04/rhel-7-network-management-nmcli-or-nmtui.html )

It has all the convenience of a GUI while being 100% cli (meaning you don't actually need a DE or WM to run it and you can run it out of the tty).