# Wifi option disappears after connecting

Tags: networking, network-manager

Since this week, I have been having issues with the wifi on my laptop. It appears that whenever I connect to the wifi at work (I have not experienced the same issue at home or at a friend's place the other day), the option for my wifi disappears after a few seconds and does not reappear. When this happens, I no longer have any wifi-related options in my system settings interface. Up until today, a reboot of my laptop would make the option reappear and work for at least a few hours again, but today I have been unable to fix the issue.

I *think* there is an issue with the NetworkManager service that causes it to disable my network chip (because I saw a line in the systemctl status of NetworkManager about this at some point), but I am unsure how to investigate for more information. Some system specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: 81LK IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming 
Kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic 
Uptime: 6 mins 
Packages: 3487 (dpkg), 8 (flatpak), 40 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q 
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
Memory: 3003MiB / 15861MiB
```

Other related checks I have done:

- Requesting the NetworkManager to start/stop/restart using systemctl does not seem to work (for some reason it does not seem able to shut down and gets stuck on the syskill interrupt that systemctl eventually sends and then nothing happens after that).
- my phone connects fine to the same network, and I can connect to the internet on my laptop via usb tethering.
- following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/398602), nmcli says that wifi is "enabled", but it lists no device for wifi.
- lspci shows that my laptop can still physically find my wifi controller, and that it is connected to the kernel modules:

  00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 10)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
  Memory at a4418000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Capabilities: 
  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
  Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.