# Wifi Enable on Close

Tags: wireless, shutdown, startup

I have a dual boot with win8.1. I rarely use it but sometimes I need to use win for things like TFTP to a router. I am more familiar with win for that so like to drop back.

In Ubuntu 14.04, I mostly I have "Wifi Enabled" turned off and it appears to totally disable the wifi card in the Acer (i5) laptop. When I boot into windows it shows "wifi Off" and I can't find a way to turn it back on in windows.

I then have to reboot to Ubuntu, Enable it, then reboot to back to windows. I know, I should remember but I am old and I am fallible. :)

Is there some way to have Ubuntu always ENable wifi on closing and DISable it on start up?

I am fairly new to Ubuntu/Linux so some specific instructions much appreciated.

Comment: @user68186 Because it auto-connects in Ubuntu and I do not want it to a lot of the time as I have several sub-nets. Sticking to the original question asked is always a good plan.

Comment: There is a common mistake that askers make that is called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/315822). Asking why you have a specific requirement is an attempt to make sure that isn't what is happening. You'd be surprised how often a simple question like that results in an answer the OP is much happier with than if the answerer had "stuck to the original question asked".

Comment: Why not click on the WiFi icon in Ubuntu > Edit connections... >  Select the SSID you don't want to auto connect > go to *General* tab and un-check "Automatically connect to this network when it is available"? Then it won't auto-connect to that specific SSID (SSID is the name of the WiFi network).

Comment: The answer to your question is in three parts: [How to switch off wifi on startup or from the console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26199/how-to-switch-off-wifi-on-startup-or-from-the-console). [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) and [Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu).

Comment: Doesn't the FN combo work in Windows to enable wifi?

Comment: @Jeremy31: Nope, nothing works, even though the DeviceManager and also the Network Sharing Center both show it as "Enabled" Windows seems powerless to change it. I tried Disable and then Enable and still nothing. Whatever Ubuntu is doing it is deep in the heart of the hardware.

Comment: @user68186: Thanks, kinda. There is a link to a more complete approach within the links you provided. http://askubuntu.com/questions/24171/how-can-i-keep-a-wireless-cards-radio-powered-off-by-default

Comment: Kinda welcome! :D You may answer your own question and accept it as the correct one.

Comment: OK, thank you. Interestingly, that link stuff also brings the Fn+F3 key back to life in Windows. All good.