# Set Ethernet as the default connection on Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 22.04 server

Tags: networking, server, wireless, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04 server edition, it can connect to the local network via either wired eithernet or Wi-Fi connections. Currently, it defaults to the Wi-Fi connection, but I want it to default to the wired connection.

Running $ ip a give the following

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:e1:39:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.253/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 64035sec preferred_lft 64035sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fee1:39d1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:e1:39:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.3/24 metric 600 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 67889sec preferred_lft 67889sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fee1:39d4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have no access to the network settings via a GUI (using a remote desktop) as all the settings in the Network Connections consol are greyed out. So can only really work with the command line over ssh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch off wifi on startup or from the console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26199/how-to-switch-off-wifi-on-startup-or-from-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

When the interface (`eth0` or `wlan0`) comes `UP`, it broadcasts a DHCP "Who Am I" message to the local network. The DHCP server responds with a message containing [IP Address, the "gateway" (where to send non-local packets) and DNS Server IP addresses, the MTU, the netmask, and more].

This data is used to configure your system's networking.

When your system boots, `eth0` startup is quick (it's just a wire), and networking is set up for `eth0` (the way you want).

`wlan0` startup is slower, but eventually starts up, and sets up `wlan0` networking, the undesired configuration.

One solution is to remove the "`Auto`" flag from the `wlan0` interface, and start `wlan0` manually, at need.

Another possible solution is my `net-o-matic` bash script:

`https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Comment: "One solution is to remove the "Auto" flag from the wlan0 interface, and start wlan0 manually, at need." How do I do that?

Comment: __1.__ "System Settings"->Network->wlan0. __2.__ See the example that comes with `net-o matic`.  __3.__Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].