# How do I pass an argument to the kernel in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, grub2, kernel, intel

> This mode is used if the intel_pstate=passive **argument is passed to the kernel in the command line** (it implies the intel_pstate=no_hwp setting too). Like in the active mode without HWP support, in this mode intel_pstate may refuse to work with the given processor if it does not recognize it.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html#passive-mode

I don't know what `command line` it is referring to. It could be the shell in bash, but I am assuming this is something you do in grub. In short; I am not sure.

### Questions:

1. How do I pass that argument, `passive` to `intel_pstate` in the kernel?
2. How can I tell what the current value of `intel_pstate` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu you can add kernel parameters in grub.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add e.g. `intel_pstate=passive` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=passive"
```

To apply this setting run

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will be used after a reboot.

You can check the current state by

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
```

Comment: Do I have to comment out `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`?

Comment: No, leave it as is. You can also add your parameter there instead of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. Like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=passive"`. Do one or the other way.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/780545/167850 It is better to add extra parameters to the latter, so the system can boot if you add something wrong.